# Flutter, Admob, Banner AdSize(width:320, height:50) not working

Tags: flutter, admob

```
_bannerAd = BannerAd(
        size: AdSize.banner,
       ............
```

this is totally working well but

```
 _bannerAd = BannerAd(
        size: AdSize(width:320, height: 50),
      .............
```

it is not working at all with below

```
error failed code : 3
```

my package is

```
google_mobile_ads: 0.11.0+4
```

and lastly the widget code is below

```
Container(
     height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
     width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
      child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd))
```

Comment: "it is not working at all failed code" is not an accurate description of the problem. Please share the exact error message, if any, with stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is less specific. however according to your error code, seems it's something not related to your AdSize.
Google play reference says The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL